# "error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`"

Tags: substrate-node-template, cargo

Currently dealing with an issue building my chain where `parity-util-mem` is conflicting with `parity-util-mem-ban` duplicates and I don't know the exact way to specify a certain version for all dependencies to use as I installed lots of pallets. Here is the full error just for reference

```
Updating crates.io index
Updating git repository `https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/pallet-did`
```

error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`.

```
... required by package `sp-core v3.0.0`
... which satisfies dependency `sp-core = "^3.0.0"` of package `frame-support v3.0.0`
... which satisfies dependency `frame-support = "^3.0.0"` of package `frame-system v3.0.0`
... which satisfies dependency `frame-system = "^3.0.0"` of package `pallet-did v3.0.0 (https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/pallet-did#8510c92b)`
... which satisfies git dependency `did` of package `node-template-runtime v2.0.0 (C:\Users\throwaway\Documents\GitHub\Argonaut-Chain\runtime)`
... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 2.0.0) of package `node-template v2.0.0 (C:\Users\throwaway\Documents\GitHub\Argonaut-Chain\node)`
```

versions that meet the requirements `^0.9.0` are: 0.9.0

the package `parity-util-mem` links to the native library `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates` as well:
package `parity-util-mem v0.7.0`

```
... which satisfies dependency `parity-util-mem = "^0.7"` of package `kvdb v0.7.0`
... which satisfies dependency `kvdb = "^0.7.0"` (locked to 0.7.0) of package `sc-client-api v2.0.0`
... which satisfies dependency `sc-client-api = "^2.0.0"` (locked to 2.0.0) of package `node-template v2.0.0 (C:\Users\throwaway)\Documents\GitHub\Argonaut-Chain\node)`
```

Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the links ='parity-util-mem' value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.

failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem` which could resolve this conflict

Answer (score 3):

This mostly happens when updating the polkadot version and you have still an old conflicting polkadot dependency.

Try to stay consistent for each `my-pallet/Cargo.toml` version

For example when you use the following.

```
frame-support = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.22"}
```

Then you should always stay with the branch `polkadot-v0.9.22`.

It seams, that your node-template-runtime is `v2.0.0`, which has conflicting dependencies to your pallet `pallet-did`.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-update.html#examples can be used if you still experience issues even after updating all cargo files. On occasion, destroying the lock file and trying to build from a clean state can resolve these as well.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout cargo tree, then you can easier see what versions are being used
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-tree.html

Comment: tried using cargo tree for this, it just ended up giving the same errors as beforehand, no matter what command I run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to upgrade your libraries and set a parity-util-mem manually in the Cargo.toml config