# error: failed to select a version with cargo check

Tags: substrate-node-template, versioning

OS : centos stream 9
CPU : x86_64
Rust : 1.61
substrate : 2022-05 3.0
polkdadot : 0.9.20
substrate-front-end : 2022-02
node : 16.14

when i study
substrate Tutorials - Add the Nicks Pallet to your Runtime
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/add-a-pallet/

when i cargo check -p node-template-runtime  , it show error
how install package which satisfies dependency

```
[lzh@c9 substrate-node-template]cargo check -p node-template-runtime
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `signature`.
    ... required by package `ecdsa v0.13.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ecdsa-core = "^0.13"` of package `k256 v0.10.4`
    ... which satisfies dependency `k256 = "^0.10.4"` of package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.22#616d33ea)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-support` of package `frame-system v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.22#616d33ea)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-system` of package `pallet-nicks v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.22#616d33ea)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `pallet-nicks` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `>=1.3.1, <1.5` are: 1.4.0, 1.3.2, 1.3.1

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `signature v1.5.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `signature = ">=1.3.1"` (locked to 1.5.0) of package `ed25519 v1.4.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ed25519 = "^1"` (locked to 1.4.1) of package `ed25519-dalek v1.0.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ed25519-dalek = "^1.0.1"` (locked to 1.0.1) of package `libp2p-core v0.30.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `libp2p-core = "^0.30.0"` (locked to 0.30.2) of package `libp2p v0.40.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `libp2p = "^0.40.0"` (locked to 0.40.0) of package `sc-cli v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.20#563f4820)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-cli` (locked to 0.10.0-dev) of package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.20#563f4820)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/node)`

failed to select a version for `signature` which could resolve this conflict
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use uniform dependencies for all crates! Using the tutorial suggests `latest` tag or explicitly calls out the correct to use tag for the template that is tagged latest at anytime.

You should update to use `latest` throughout. And you may need to update your Cargo.lock file  to remove any confusion for cargo on deps.

Comment: See also https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/error-failed-to-select-a-version-for-parity-util-mem